# Can OSM's iD editor be used on MapBox

Tags: mapbox, id-editor

I am setting up a community-based mapping solution for a local NGO. They need their own maps and I have decided to go with MapBox.

It's good to use MapBox technology as it is scalable, modifiable and, using their [iD editor](http://ideditor.com/), should allow user edits.

However, I cannot work out how to make my maps editable.

For example, how would I add an editor that would allow this [layer of points](http://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/robinlovelace.urban-harvest/page.html#12/53.9962/-1.5244) to be modified, allowing new users to create new points just like on OpenStreetMap (OSM)?

I know it can be done with GeoServer, but want to retain the beautiful simplicity of MapBox for this one.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is to use [geojson.io](http://geojson.io).

I was directed to this by MapBox developers on their IRC channel - allows multi-person on-line editing of geo data. It's lightweight, open sources, allows control of the data and, with github teams, allows it to be collaborative or taken into private ownership.

Regarding iD, no it's not possible unless you are editing an OSM-based geo-database seems to be the answer atm, although this may change, as it's a completely [open source project](https://github.com/systemed/iD), so can be forked in any direction.

geojson.io and the other technologies MapBox will be very useful in the GIS/web mapper's toolkit in the coming years.

Answer (score 1):

This might be possible depending on how much editing you'd like available for your maps. Please see [Leaflet.draw](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/leaflet-draw/) for more information on adding and editing interface for your map. [Any edit events](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw#events) would need to be saved [to a static geoJSON asset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11240996/write-javascript-output-to-file-on-server) and then reloaded onto the map. If you're only looking to collaboratively add markers then mapbox's markerlayer has [a `loadURL` method](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/geojson-marker-from-url/).

For a more collaborative editing experience I'd recommend [together.js](https://togetherjs.com/)

FYI, geojson.io's interface will be better integrated with mapbox.com within the coming year.